# How to change backgroud color of text Entry box

Tags: go, user-interface, data-entry, andlabs-ui

I am trying to use [andlabs/ui](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/andlabs/ui) for a simple GUI application.

Is it possible to change background color of [ui.Entry](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/andlabs/ui#Entry) text entry boxes?

I see that there is a [TextBackground](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/andlabs/ui#TextBackground) attribute available. However following code does not work:

```
var ent = ui.NewEntry()
ent.TextBackground(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)
```

The error is:

```
ent.TextBackground undefined (type *ui.Entry has no field or method TextBackground)
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: You typed "TextBackgroud" instead of "TextBackground". Could that just be it?

Comment: Apologies for the typo. But correctly spelled "TextBackground" also give error.

Comment: I'm afraid that there is not way to change the background color of an Entry as of now. TextBackground is supposed to be used to construct an [AttributedString](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/andlabs/ui#AttributedString), which is in turn to be used by [DrawNewTextLayout](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/andlabs/ui#DrawNewTextLayout). See an example here: https://github.com/andlabs/ui/blob/70a69d6ae31ed9d8bb0619a191179c63d846ab8e/examples/drawtext.go#L53

Comment: Can text font be specified and changed in any widget such as Label/Entry/Button?